# jQuery - Programmatically Trigger Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to programmatically trigger a click event that's being handled by jQuery.  Here's the current code:

```
var $thumbs = $('#PhotoGalleryThumbs .tile');
var $zoom = $('#PhotoGallery #PhotoGalleryZoom img');
var $description = $('#PhotoGallery #PhotoGalleryDescription');

$thumbs.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $thumb = $(this);
    $thumb.addClass('selected')
        .siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $zoom.attr('src', $thumb.children('a').attr('href'));
    $description.html($thumb.find('img').attr('alt'));
});
```

I am having a mental block working out how to create a function out of the event handling code and then arbitrarily calling it for an element in the `$thumbs` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$thumbs.click();
```

This would trigger the click event. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Optionally, you could specifically target a given element, rather than the entire set of them. `$('#yourTarget').click();`

Comment: $thumbs is a collection of objects.  I want to select a specific object and call the `click()` event on that.

Comment: as S Pangborn said, $('#yourSpecificElement').click()

Comment: I need it to be an indexed selection, like an array.  Something like `$thumbs[7].click()`.  I thought that `.index()` might do it, but that seems to do the reverse of what I need.

Comment: $($thumbs[7]).click() would do

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous suggestion of

```
$($thumbs[7]).click();
```

you can use

```
$thumbs.eq(7).click();
```

For clarification, array indexing into a jQuery collection gives you the DOM Element at that position, whereas `.eq(n)` gives you a new jQuery object which references only the indexed element.

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Thanks Geoff, I'll keep that one in my back pocket for sure!