# Jquery change onclick for first <a>

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="navi">
   <a onclick="GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(1,5)" href="#"></a>
   <a onclick="GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(2,5)" href="#" ></a>
   <a onclick="GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(3,5)" href="#" class="active"></a>
   <a onclick="GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(4,5)" href="#"></a> 
   <a onclick="GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(5,5)" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

... and when a next/prev button is clicked, i.e.

```
 <div class="next">Next</div>
 <div class="prev">Prev</div>
```

I need the Jquery to reset active class to the first `<a>` and fire the onclick event for the first `<a>` too.

I've got `$('.navi a').removeClass('active');
            $('.navi a:first-child').addClass('active');` but don't know how to fire the first onclick event.

Many thanks

Comment: Having next/prev button seems odd when you only set `active` on the first element after clicking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Programmatically Trigger Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700231/jquery-programmatically-trigger-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.navi a:first-child').click();
```

EDIT,

In this case you know what function is, why don't you just call

```
GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(1,5);
```

Also, make sure you run it when the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navi a').removeClass('active'); 
    $('.navi a:first-child').addClass('active').click();
})
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried this, trouble is I have loads of the same thing on the page, and it's not calling the right one! ... I'll take another look

Comment: Turned out the order of my code was a bit wrong, but that worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just call that function after setting it as active!!

Fire GetTagDataOnPageChangeNumeric(1,5) manually.

I'm not sure whether you want more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `trigger` function to fire the click event:

```
$(".navi a:first-child").trigger("click");
```