# jquery - trigger listener programmatically

Tags: jquery, listener

This listener is currently triggered with a click in a ref in div shown below.
Using jquery, how can I trigger the event programmatically? - or may be better to re-write the listener.

```
$("#flipPad a:not(.revert)").bind("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#flipbox").flip({
        direction: $this.attr("rel"),
        color: $this.attr("rev"),
        content: $this.attr("title"), 
        onBefore: function(){$(".revert").show()}
    })
    return false;
});
```

html:

```
<div id="flipbox">Message1</div>
<div id="flipPad">
<a href="#" class="left" rel="rl" rev="#39AB3E" title="Change content as <em>you</em> like!">left</a>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Programmatically Trigger Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700231/jquery-programmatically-trigger-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#flipPad a:not(.revert)').click();
```

You can also do this:

```
$('#flipPad a:not(.revert)').trigger('click');
```

Links to documentation:

- [jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (see version #3)
- [jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

This should trigger it programmatically (fire the event handler):

```
$("#flipPad a:not(.revert)").click();
```